# Change position/size of chrome notifications on OSX?

Tags: google-chrome

Currently the Google Chrome notification appears in the top right (and its a bit big for my liking). Is there anyway to setup position/size? (even a dirty hack)

Edit: as comment below looks like there is no way

Comment: Google wins :(
There seems to be no way to do this, as i see a lot of people with the same problem but nobody has found a way around. Tried to see if I could hack it by making an extension but API doesn't allow that either.